# get applications associated with certain file on macOS

Tags: macos, applescript

I can find the default application associated with a certain file with this script.

```
tell application "Finder"
    default application of (info for POSIX file "/Users/vk/Pictures/DSCF3320.jpg")
end tell
```

But is there any way to list ALL applications associated with this file? I.e. the same list which is displayed in Finder when you click "Open with"?

The code is in AppleScript but I do not necessarily require the solution to be in AppleScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found that this simple python script does exactly what I need:

```
import sys
from AppKit import NSURL
from LaunchServices import LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL, kLSRolesAll
     
url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(sys.argv[1])
for url in LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(url, kLSRolesAll):
    print url.path()
```

Comment: Note: This may not return all _applications_ listed under the **Open With** _context menu item_ in **Finder**. Case in point, on my systems for e.g. `/path/to/filename.jpg` there are 12 items listed and this only returned 7 of them. Noticeably missing were the 4 web browsers installed on my system that show on the the **Open With** _context menu item_ but not in the output from the _code_ in this answer.

Comment: @user3439894. I think, passing kLSRolesAll instead of kLSRolesEditor should return all of your 12 items.

Comment: @Robert Kniazidis, Is it safe to assume that the first item returned will always be what the current default for it is? (Just curious.)

Comment: @Robert Kniazidis You are right, thanks. I updated my answer to use kLSRolesAll. It seems to list all the applications. Just a bit out of order when compared to Finder context menu. It would be best to have them in the same order, but it is not that big deal if they are not.

Comment: @user3439894, I don't know. The documentation of method says something about best order on macOS 10.15 and later, but nothing about default item. So, need testings.

Comment: Hopefully, this refers to the same thing but in 'LSInfo.h' on my archaic system, it states that the 'order of the resulting array is undefined' and to get the default application 'use LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL'.